# Integrating a Modulus Under the Complex Path Integral on a Circle

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

I have an integral that involves a modulus term under the integral sign, that I'm not too sure how to deal with.

$$\int_{|z|=R} \dfrac{|dz|}{|z-c|^4}, R > 0, |c| \neq R$$

OK, so now suppose I know how to deal with the $|dz|$ term. I still don't know what to do with the term on the bottom. I could parameterize $z(\theta) = Re^{i\theta}$, then $z'(\theta) = iRe^{i\theta}$, and $|z'(\theta)| = R$, so

$$\int_{|z|=R} \dfrac{|dz|}{|z-c|^4} = \int_{|z|=R} \dfrac{1}{|z(\theta)-c|^4} |z'(\theta)| d\theta = R\int_{0}^{2\pi} \dfrac{1}{|Re^{i\theta}-c|^4} d\theta$$

And now I'm not sure how to proceed. This doesn't seem to fit a Cauchy-esque theorem that would give me that this is multiple of $2\pi i$, or something to that effect.

Comment: are you sure it is $|dz|$ instead of just $dz$? Because the absolute value is not complex differentiable

Comment: yes, it's $|dz|$. It's a modulus, not absolute value. So, $|dz| = \sqrt{dx^2+dy^2};$ where $z = x + iy$.

Comment: @Masacroso It is not path-independent but $\int_\gamma |f(z)|\, |dz| = \int_0^1 |f(\gamma(t))| \ | \gamma'(t)| dt$ is the most obvious bound we can find for $\int_\gamma f(z)dz$. @ Joe Since $z \overline{z} = R^2$ you can find $g_c$ (meromorphic) such that $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \dfrac{1}{|Re^{i\theta}-c|^4} R d\theta = \int_{|z|=R} g_c(z)dz = 2i\pi \sum Res(g_c)$

Comment: @Masacroso ? The meaning is clear when you see it, I just defined it, it is compatible with the Riemann sums definition of $\int_\gamma f(z) dz$, everybody use it.

Comment: @reuns you are right, my bad.